# How to use AWS SSM parameter store values in Cloudformation template conditionals?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, ssm

I have configured a key value pair in the AWS SSM parameter store UI as `my-ssm-key` = `ssm-value`.

I have the following YAML template for CF built on Serverless:

```
service: redirect-test

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8

  environment:
    ssm_value: '{{resolve:ssm:my-ssm-key:1}}'
    ssm_value_is_correct: !If [SSM_KEY_IS_CORRECT, yes, no]

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello

resources:
  Conditions:
    SSM_KEY_IS_CORRECT:
      !Equals
        - '{{resolve:ssm:my-ssm-key:1}}'
        - 'ssm-value'
```

On deploying the stack, environment variables are being set to `ssm_value` = `ssm-value` and `ssm_value_is_correct` = `no`.

Why is the conditional statement resolving to "no" instead of "yes"? What is the correct way to use SSM parameter store values in conditionals?

Param store screenshot: [image: SSM param store screenshot]
Env variables screenshot: [image: Env variables screenshot]

Comment: why dont you also set `SSM_KEY_IS_CORRECT ` as an environment variable, so you can see how is it resolving ?

Comment: @ArunK I've tried doing `foo: SSM_KEY_IS_CORRECT` but in that case `SSM_KEY_IS_CORRECT` is just treated as a string and not a variable. So the environment variable is just `"SSM_KEY_IS_CORRECT"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by using this CF template:

```
service: redirect-test

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8

  environment:
    ssm_value: !Ref MySSMValue
    ssm_value_is_correct: !If [SSM_KEY_IS_CORRECT, yes, no]

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello

resources:
  Conditions:
    SSM_KEY_IS_CORRECT:
      !Equals
        - !Ref MySSMValue
        - ssm-value

  Parameters:
    MySSMValue:
      Description: My SSM Value
      Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
      Default: my-ssm-key
```

[image: Environment variables with correct expected values]